# using if else in mysql user defined function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function, sql-null, mysql-function

This is my query that basically takes two numbers  that adds them and multiplies the sum by  10

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION tot(a int(4),b INT(4)) RETURNS INT(4)
BEGIN
RETURN ROUND((a+b)*10/9);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

everything is working fine , but I was wondering if there was a way I could add an IF ELSE
that checks if any of of the values entered is null and if so the null value is assigned a value of zero

I've tried this but I'm getting an error

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION tot(a int(4),b INT(4)) RETURNS INT(4)
BEGIN
IF (a = "") then
a=0;
ELSE IF (b = "")
b=0;
ELSE
END IF;
RETURN ROUND((a+b)*10/9);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `NULL` is not the same thing as an empty string.

Comment: `ELSE IF` should only be used when the conditions are mutually exclusive. What if both `a` and `b` are null?

Comment: Why do you think `ELSE a=a;` is necessary? Why would you need to assign a variable to itself.

Comment: I just put the a=a  by mistake but I've edited it out and for the both b=" "and a='' " I had not thought of that but GMB has provide a perfect solution with coalesce()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if there was a way I could add an IF ELSE that checks if any of of the values entered is null and if so the null value is assigned a value of zero

You can just use `coalesce()` to assign a default to `null` parameters:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION tot(a int(4),b INT(4)) RETURNS INT(4)
BEGIN
    RETURN ROUND((COALESCE(a, 0) + COALESCE(b, 0)) * 10 / 9);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```